# Check one array is completely present in another

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 4 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 5 ) ) 

$array2 = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [usr_id] => 4 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [usr_id] => 5 ) )
```

I want to check, all elements of `$array2` is present in `$array1` or not.

How can I do that?

I have searched, but couldn't find a suitable solution for my array.

Note: I want this comparison, without changing the array format.

Comment: Would you like to compare the elements by reference (since they are objects), or by value? By the way, for your example neither of them is true, because of the difference in user_id vs. usr_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$fullyExists = (count($array2) == count(array_intersect($array2, $array1));
```

Comment: This will not work for my array since they are objects

Comment: Convert objects to array before do this. It will make you easy to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it there is a PHP function for that, but you can do your own:

```
function arrayIsIncluded($array1,$array2){
    foreach($array2 as $key => $value){
        if (!in_array($value,$array1)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This takes more efforts. Think easy & smart way.

Comment: It's quite long, but i think it's faster than your solution, because you have to do a full intersection first and then compare. My function stops is the result is false.

Comment: User define functions working slower than library function. So always insist to use those first.

Comment: This is discutable. It may be true concerning time efficiency, but not about the memory used.

Comment: What if we have hundred of values in both arrays ?? You need to check for every values in smaller array. This is not a good logic.

Comment: And how do you think an intersection works? It arrays are not sorted, it's the same job. But i can agree with you on this point (time efficiency). However, doing an intersection will cost memory, mainly if the arrays are large

Answer (score 0):

try [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$contains = count(array_intersect($array2, $array1)) == count($array2);
```

Comment: And how it is different from Alexander's answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$checking = (count(array_intersect($arr2, $arr1)) == count($arr2))?1:0;
```

If all elements of `$arr2` is present in `$arr1` then it will return 1.